# How to create a console Timer for quiz Application

Tags: c#, timer

I want to create a timer of 30 seconds and after 30 seconds the timer should end and display some message.

In those 30 seconds I want user to enter an option if he fails to enter a option then I need to show some message like timed out.

```
public void AskEasyQues(EasyQuestion easyQuestion)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Here is Your:"+sQcount+" Question:");
    System.Console.WriteLine("***********************************");
    System.Console.WriteLine("Question is of The Category:"+easyQuestion.MCat);
    System.Console.WriteLine("***********************************");
    System.Console.WriteLine(easyQuestion.MDescription);
    System.Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
    System.Console.WriteLine("1:"+easyQuestion.MOption1+"         "+"2:"+easyQuestion.MOption2);
    System.Console.WriteLine();
    System.Console.WriteLine("3:"+easyQuestion.MOption3+"         "+"4:"+easyQuestion.MOption4);
    System.Console.WriteLine();
    System.Console.WriteLine("Enter your Choice:");

    for (int a = 60; a >= 0; a--)
    {
            Console.Write("\rGenerating Preview in {0:00}", a);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    } 
       
    string ans = Console.ReadLine();

    if(ans == easyQuestion.MAnswer)
    {
            mNoOfQuesAnswerd++;
            System.Console.WriteLine();
            System.Console.WriteLine("------Well Played Champion!!!!!!-----");
            sPlayerScore=sPlayerScore+100;
    }
    else
    {
            System.Console.WriteLine();
            System.Console.WriteLine("------Wrong Choice Lets Move On--------");
    }

    System.Console.WriteLine();
    System.Console.WriteLine("Press any Key To Continue For Next Question");
    Console.ReadLine();

    System.Console.WriteLine();
    System.Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");

    sQcount = sQcount + 1;
    Console.Clear();
}
```

This is my code and I have also tried simply a countdown timer using for loop like below:

```
for (int a = 60; a >= 0; a--)
{
      Console.Write("\rGenerating Preview in {0:00}", a);    
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

but it is not i want to implement please share a minute to help me.

Comment: Sir can u help me with the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to use is a Timer.

Firstly add the following namespace.

```
using System.Timers;
```

Next add a modular/global variable to do the timing.

```
static Timer questionTimer = new Timer(30000) //Time in milliseconds to fire event..
```

Next you need to wire up to the Elapsed event and enable the timer.

```
questionTimer.Elapsed += QuestionTimer_Elapsed;
questionTimer.Enabled = true;
```

and your method for time up might look something like this.

```
private static void QuestionTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Time up!");
    questionTimer.Stop();
}
```

and finally you would start this timer every time you display a new question. (Don't forget to stop the timer if the question is answered correctly otherwise the event will still fire)

```
questionTimer.Start(); //Start question timer...
Console.Write("What is 5+5? "); //Ask the question...
string ans = Console.ReadLine(); //Get the user input...
if (ans == "10")
{
    //If it's correct stop timing...
    Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
    questionTimer.Stop();
}
```

I hope this helps you and if you need any further explanation, leave a comment. :)

Comment: Sir I need something like this:question: what is xyz?

Comment: its options and timer in console showing you have " z "seconds left

Comment: if the user enter his choice in t seconds then its fine else i have to display timedout.It would be great if u help me to do this

Comment: That is what it does, I have added a bit more where you would answer the question, does it help?

Comment: s sir it really helped me if u could tell me how to display in console like u have z seconds left

Comment: Anyway u have helped me a lot

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean. You would have to write a new line for each countdown because of how the console works. Which I don't think would be a good user experience as they would not have time to type an answer before the next write.

Comment: so i cant do like this Console.WriteLine("You have"+count+"seconds left"); where it displays you have 30,29,....0  seconds left I cant Do like this sir?

Comment: I have added another answer which I believe is more what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I mis-understood your question in my previous answer.

What you want is a line that counts down the time remaining?

Similar process of wiring up a timer, but also create a int variable called secondCounter and we will set the interval for our Timer to 1000. (1 second).

Our timer elapsed method now looks something like this:

```
private static void QuestionTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    secondCounter = secondCounter + 1;

    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2); //This is a row number...
    Console.Write("\rSeconds Remaining: {0}: ", 30 - secondCounter);

    if (secondCounter >= 30)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Time's up!");
        questionTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Then you will handle your question logic outside of the timer.

```
questionTimer.Start();
Console.WriteLine("What is 5 + 5?");

var input = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine($"You anwsered {input}");
questionTimer.Stop();
```